# Update column of duplicated rows oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table in oracle with 3 columns:

```
create table pruebaBorrado (
 num1 varchar2(24), 
 num2 varchar2(24),
 num3 varchar2(24));
```

and the table contains:

```
insert into pruebaBorrado values ('1','1','1');
insert into pruebaBorrado values ('1','1','1'); 
insert into pruebaBorrado values ('1','1','1');
insert into pruebaBorrado values ('2','2','2');
insert into pruebaBorrado values ('2','2','2'); 
insert into pruebaBorrado values ('3','3','3');
```

As you see, there are duplicated rows. I want change the 'num3' column only for the duplicated rows and to obtain the follow:

```
'1', '1', '1' 
'1', '1', '1A' 
'1', '1', '1B' 
'2', '2', '2' 
'2', '2', '2A' 
'3', '3', '3'
```

How can I make this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have to change it using letters?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit brute force, but it does work:

```
update pruebaBorrado
    set num3 = (case (select count(*)
                      from pruebaBorrado pb
                      where pb.num1 = pruebaBorrado.num1 and pb.num2 = pruebaBorrado.num2 and
                            pb.rowid <= pruebaBorrado.rowid
                     )
                 when 1 then num3
                 when 2 then num3 || 'A'
                 when 3 then num3 || 'B'
                 when 4 then num3 || 'C'
                 else num3 || 'X'
                 end
                );
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e81d2/1).

EDIT:

The following should also work:

```
update pruebaBorrado
    set num3 = num3 ||
               substr(' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,
                      (select count(*)
                       from pruebaBorrado pb
                       where pb.num1 = pruebaBorrado.num1 and pb.num2 = pruebaBorrado.num2 and
                             pb.rowid <= pb.rowid
                      ), 1);
```

Comment: I have this error: ORA-00904: "PB"."ROW_ID":invalid identifier

Comment: @mcl . . . A typo.  I changed it in the SQL Fiddle but not in the answer.  There is no underscore in `rowid`.

Comment: If you see your solution, it is not what I want. Watch my post please

Comment: @mcl . . . The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This works, tested it. I have used here chr() which converts ascii value to char to get A,B,C .. and rank function.

```
update pruebaBorrado pb1
      set num3 = num3 || ( 
             select chr(temp.rank+63)  
            from ( select rowid, rank() over ( partition by num1,num2,num3     order by rowid ) rank 
                   from pruebaborrado pb2 ) temp
             where 
           temp.rowid = pb1.rowid
          and temp.rank >1
);
```

Logic goes as below:

1. Rank function will rank each duplicate row like below:

   **num1|num2|num3|rank**
    
    1|   1| 1  | 1
    1|   1| 1  | 2
    1|   1| 1  | 3
2. After this rank is used for generating ASCII for A,B,C by adding 63 to it. 63 is used since we need to append A for first duplicate whose rank is 2 and ASCII value of A is 65.